# If X is a symmetric diagonal dominant PD matrix, C and K are diagonal positive matrices. Can I find some bounds on C, K to make K(CX +I) PD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $X$ be a positive symmetric matrix. $X$ can be understood as an inverse of a reduced incidence matrix of a tree-structured network. Hence, for the first row, $$\sum_{k:k\sim 1} x_{ik}$$ includes $x_{10}$, $0$ means the root. However, for the reduced matrices, its column is deleted, so there is no index $0$ anywhere else in the matrix, and which makes the matrix nonsingular and positive definite (PD).

Some nodes are connected. We use $I \sim j$ to say that $i\neq j$ and $i$ and $j$ are neighbors. We know that $X$ is a PD matrix. For PD, we only consider real numbers, not complex numbers.

$$\begin{equation}
  [X]_{ij} =
    \begin{cases}
      \sum\limits_{k:k\sim i} x_{ik} & \text{if $i=j$}\\
      -x_{ij} & \text{if $i\sim j$}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}$$
We also have diagonal matrices $C$ and $K$, we want to somehow bound $C$ and $K$ to make

$$[K(CX+I)+(XC+I)K]$$

a PD matrix.

**Edit:** Or relax it to $(CX+I)^\top(CX+I)+K(CX+I)+(XC+I)K$ and makes it PD.

**Edit 2:** A trivial answer is $K=C^{-1}$, I want something beyond that, like K can be how much different with $C^{-1}$.

Actually, in my case, $C$ has relatively some entries, so in practice, it shows like a PD. I want some hints so that I can rigorously prove it with some bounds on $C$ or $K$ or both.

Thank you in advance for any possible help.

Comment: Yes, it is non-Hermitian. It is something I met when trying to prove convergence.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am considering real values only. For $z\in R^n$, $z^\top K(CX+I)z>0$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to consider such a “positive definite” matrix? What is it used for?

Comment: When proving the convergence of some controllers, we want some Definite matrices, such that the Lyapunov is going down. @user1551. In this kind of situation, complex numbers are not necessary.

Comment: The matrix $X$ is a Z-matrix, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics), and from $X$ being PD it ends up being a non-singular M-matrix too, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix look up its properties regarding stability.

Comment: Please clarify: (1) Is $X$ symmetric? In the title, $X$ is supposed to be symmetric, but this is not specified in the question body (it is unclear whether your graph is directed or undirected). (2) Isn't $X$ positive semidefinite rather than positive definite? Apparently $X$ is singular, because its row sums are zero.

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, why append Edit sections? Just refine the question

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the tips, I will do it next time.

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed and also pointed out by the others, the reduced matrix $X$, apart from being symmetric positive semidefinite, has some special structures: it is diagonally dominant and it is an M-matrix. In what follows, however, I will find a sufficient condition for $K(CX+I)$ to be “non-symmetric positive definite” using only the positive semidefiniteness of $X$, without regard to these special structures. Since this sufficient condition is applicable to a generic positive semidefinite matrix $X$, you may probably find it too limiting.

Let $D=KC$. The symmetric part of $K(CX+I)$ is then $\frac12(DX+XD+2K)$. It is positive definite if and only if
$$
\lambda_\min(DX+XD+2K)>0.\tag{1}
$$
Let $k$ and $c$ be the diagonals of $K$ and $C$ respectively. Their Hadamard product $d=k\circ c$ is the diagonal of $D$. Let $e$ be the vector of ones. Then $DX+XD=(de^T+ed^T)\circ X$ is a principal submatrix of $(de^T+ed^T)\otimes X$. Therefore $\lambda_\min(DX+XD)\ge\lambda_\min\left((de^T+ed^T)\otimes X\right)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
&\lambda_\min(DX+XD+2K)\\
&\ge\lambda_\min(DX+XD)+2\lambda_\min(K)\\
&\ge\lambda_\min\left((de^T+ed^T)\otimes X\right)+2\lambda_\min(K)\\
&=\lambda_\min(de^T+ed^T)\lambda_\max(X)+2\lambda_\min(K)\quad\text{(because $\lambda_\min(de^T+ed^T)\le0$)}\\
&=-(\|e\|_2\|d\|_2-e^Td)\lambda_\max(X)+2\lambda_\min(K).\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus $(1)$ holds if the expression on line $(2)$ is positive, i.e., it holds if the following sufficient condition is satisfied:
$$
(\|e\|_2\|d\|_2-e^Td)\lambda_\max(X)<2\min_{1\le i\le n}k_i.\tag{3}
$$
If the computation of $\lambda_\max(X)$ is too expensive, you may replace $\lambda_\max(X)$ by some larger but easily computable quantity, such as $\|X\|_\infty=\max_{1\le i\le n}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_{ij}|$, to obtain another sufficient condition with a stronger requirement.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! It shows great insight! I have a quick question, suppose  K is only a positive semi-definite diagonal matrix, can I apply a similar method to find a condition such that $(CX+I)^\top(CX+I)+K(CX+I)+(XC+I)K$ is positive definite?

Comment: this proof is more than helpful, can you tell me how to acknowledge your help in my future related paper? @user1551

Comment: @jason By a similar argument, the minimum eigenvalue of
$$
A=(CX+I)^T(CX+I)+K(CX+I)+(XC+I)K
$$
is bounded below by
$$
\begin{align}
&\lambda_\min(CX^2C)+\lambda_\min(CX+XC)+2+\lambda_\min(DX+XD)+2\lambda_\min(K)\\
&\ge c_\min\,\lambda_\min(X)^2-(\|e\|_2\|c\|_2-e^Tc)\lambda_\max(X)+2-(\|e\|_2\|d\|_2-e^Td)\lambda_\max(X)+2k_\min,
\end{align}
$$
where $c_\min=\min_ic_i$ and $k_\min=\min_ik_i$ (with $k_\min=0$ when $K$ is singular). Thus $A$ is PD when
$$
\left[(\|e\|_2\|c\|_2-e^Tc)+(\|e\|_2\|d\|_2-e^Td)\right]\lambda_\max(X)
<c_\min\,\lambda_\min(X)^2+2(k_\min+1).
$$

Comment: @jason For citation, see [this example](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4352), [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3460) or [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107963).

Comment: thanks so much for the help,will do